# Python program that extracts column data by command line arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, file, command-line-arguments

My python program **extract.py** is trying to extract "column" data from text files (using a command line argument to indicate which column to extract data from).

For example; **animals.txt** contains...

bird dog cat pigeon

tiger lion insect frog

leopard monkey gorilla ape

---

In the command line...

```
python extract.py 1 animals.txt
```

Is meant to extract bird, tiger, leopard (first column of data).

```
python extract.py 3 animals.txt
```

Is meant to extract pigeon, frog, ape (third column of data).

---

My extract.py currently contains

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[2] # Text file input is stored in file_name

with open(file_name, "r") as my_file:
    contents = my_file.readlines()
    print(contents)
```

Specifically, I'm struggling to **extract the column data** (first column, second column, third column) **based off the argument** of 1, 2, 3 respectively.

It could help to know that **each word on a line is separated by just one space in the text file**.

Cheers for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[2]        # Text file input is stored in file_name
col_numbr = int( sys.argv[1] ) # column number

with open(file_name, "r") as my_file:
    for each_line in my_file:            # taking line by line

        line_list = each_line.split(' ') # each line is splited at space 
                                         # and made into a list

        print ( line_list[col_numbr-1] ) # -1 is added to start indexing from 1
```

Try this code.

Each character in the text file matters, so there shouldn't be any rouge spaces or newline characters.